# show title in font awesome icon in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, font-awesome

I have a fa icon I am using on a page the fa-info-circle.  When I hover on desktop view I can see my title info appear.  However I cannot get this to show up in mobile view.  How can I get the title to appear in mobile view, hovering or clicking on it does not do anything.

Comment: This is nothing to do with code - it's your design choice. (Or that of your design team.) Obviously hover effects won't work on devices without a mouse. (Although I believe iOS does make it happen when you touch the element.)

Comment: Hover event trigers by mouse. You have no mouse on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries, [check this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: That doesn't really help.